# Base deprecates some useful functions

Tags: ocaml, utop

I am used to using the standard function `print_int` in OCaml, but when I open the library `Base` by Jane Street, as recommended in the book Real World OCaml, I obtain a deprecation warning:

```
utop # print_int;;
- : int -> unit = <fun>
utop # open Base;;
utop # print_int;;
Line 1, characters 0-9:
Alert deprecated: Base.print_int
- : int -> unit = <fun>
```

Even worse, when I build it with `dune`, as recommended in that book, warnings become errors.  What should I do ? Replace `print_int` with `printf "%i"` ? or with `Caml.print_int` ? Both seem to work but look needlessly complicated. Something else ?
Thank you.

Comment: IIRC, Jane Street moved all IO stuff into the `Stdio` library.

Comment: Link to Jane Street [Stdio module documentation](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/v0.13/doc/stdio/Stdio/index.html) for the OP's reference.

Comment: Thanks, I had read it and that's why I had proposed `printf "%i"` in my question. But which of the two alternatives mentioned in my question should I prefer ?

Comment: To the context, Base is deprecating those functions automatically using a script. So it wasn't a thoughtful process. Basically, they deprecate any function that comes from the standard library even if they do not provide any alternative. I would use `printf` or switch to the `Format` or `Fmt` module to fulfill my printing needs, they are much more powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered here: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/v0.13/doc/base/index.html#using-the-ocaml-standard-library-with-base

> Base is intended as a full stdlib replacement. As a result, after an open Base, all the modules, values, types, etc., coming from the OCaml standard library that one normally gets in the default environment are deprecated.
>
> In order to access these values, one must use the `Caml` library, which re-exports them all through the toplevel name `Caml`: `Caml.String`, `Caml.print_string`, ...

Comment: Thanks, I read it and that's why I proposed `Caml.print_int` in my question.  But which of the two alternatives mentioned in my question should I prefer ?

Comment: That is a subjective choice, I'd recommend using your judgment to make the choice. It may vary as the situation changes.